# Answer unavailable to edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, edits

When I attempt to edit a specific answer, I cannot seem to edit it. The edit (button, I guess) is greyed out, but only for that specific answer. I can still edit other questions/answers, but not a specific answer

[image: greyed-out edit link]

It still allows me to edit other questions/answers, but not that answer. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13288914/1406409

Comment: There was an edit sugested an hour ago. FYI: When the link is greyed out you can see the reason why you can't edit if you hover over the link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the "edit" link is grayed out, it has a tooltip showing for which reason editing is not possible.

If there is a pending edit, the tooltip will say, "Another edit has already been suggested."

[image: screenshot]

A similar tooltip is shown on meta sites, when you are not a 2K user.

[image: screenshot]

If you have enough reputation, and a question is locked, the "edit" link appears grayed out, with a tooltip saying, "Post is locked."

[image: screenshot]